# How to choose third 20% of part of dataset?

Tags: r

Assume i have a dataset like:

```
df<-data.frame(data=(1:100))
```

**how can i select the nth 20% of my data?**

let's say, i need to access the third 20%, which contains numbers between 40-60

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick function to call for the specific rows based on percentage of rows of data

```
rowNumbs <- function(i, perc, df){
       ((i - 1)*ceiling(perc*nrow(df)) + 1) : (i*ceiling(perc*nrow(df)))
       }
```

where i is the nth set, perc is the percentage and df is the data.frame.

To call the third 20% of your data.frame:

```
df[rowNumbs(3, .2, df), ]

[1] 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60
```

Comment: in line `rowNumbs(3, .2, df)` should it be `.2` or `0.2` ?

Comment: `0.2` is the same as `.2` on R console.

Comment: A similar way that doesn't rely on sorted data: `df[ findInterval(df$data, quantile(df$data, c(.4,.6))) == 1, ]` (assuming OP cares about values, not row positions).

Answer (score 2):

Using the function `ntile` from the `dplyr` package. We divide the data frame into 5 buckets and take the third one.

```
library(dplyr)

# One line
df[ntile(df$data, 5) == 3, ]

# Using pipes
df %>% 
  mutate(n = ntile(data, 5)) %>% 
  filter(n == 3) %>% 
  select(data)
```

Output:

```
[1] 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60
```